# DHCP Scopes For 2 VLANs

Tags: dhcp-server, windows-server-2019

I am running a Windows Server 2019 as a DC running DHCP. I am running a single scope running through a NIC to handle addresses for our small network. I am being asked to add a second DHCP scope so it can manage IPs on another network using a second NIC already installed to ports on a separate VLAN than the existing one. Our system does not have any routers in it and only uses level 2 network switches Cisco C9300-24Ts.

- NIC #1: 192.168.1.10 [VLAN 10] (Exisiting)
- NIC #2: 192.165.5.10 [VLAN 20] (New)

The existing NIC and DHCP scope work great without an issue. The New Scope I set up for NIC 2 is running but when I connect to ports on that VLAN that that NIC is served from I don't get an address.What am I missing? Did I do something wrong?

These 2 NICs are connected to 2 separate isolated networks.

Comment: Have you used wireshark to capture DHCP packets on both NICs?

Comment: @Bert I have not really dabbled in wireshark. When I have used it, it was all a little overwhelming when you get a sample. I am not sure how to use it.

Comment: Are both NIC's bound to IPv4 in the DHCP server?

Comment: @joeqwerty They are both bound to a different IPV4 address but completely different isolated networks.

Comment: If your network does not have routers, how then will you route traffic between the two VLANs? Also, if you do have a router (which you need) it is better to configure it to use DHCP relay for the new network. That scales better than giving your servers network interfaces in each and every new network.

Comment: Since it seems you are not responsible for the network, perhaps you can ask the network engineer to help you with Wireshark. It is not that difficult once you understand a few basics. It will provide invaluable troubleshooting information. If the client and server really are in the same (new) network, the server should see the DHCP Discover message and send an Offer. Perhaps you can see these Discover/Offer messages also in your DHCP server logs.

Answer (score -1):

You need to configure the DHCP relay on your switch to sent the DHCP packets from the new VLAN to your server. You do not need the second NIC involved.

Comment: I am a little confused on how that works. A NIC can only have one address, how can it serve more than one IP scope?

Comment: @JukEboX A NIC has only one MAC address. It can have many IP addresses, and be in many VLANs, each with one or more IP addresses. As I'm a Linux admin I'll have to leave the specifics of setting it up to a Windows person.

Comment: Switches can't do DHCP relay.  You need a router for that.

Comment: @RonTrunk "Layer 3 Switch"

Comment: I did not spot this answer before making my comment. I agree with the advice but it does not solve the user's issue.